# Hadoop launch modified jar

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

i launched my jar and i noticed an exception in a class called "TreeFra". So i changed some things and eliminated this class. I have exported the jar and launched it but i got the same exception on that class that NO longer exist.

So i formatted the hdfs, stopped all slaves and the master, launched them, exported the jar again and launched the new jar.

Result? I got again the same exception (in the stacktrace says some as "Illegal Argument at TreeFra:100") but that class not more exist

What can i do now?

Comment: Code. Code and exceptions. We need them.

Comment: Maybe your old jar is being picked up from a different location.

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning your project, again make the jar. This time save it with a new name. And try to put some logging just before the line you are getting the exception. This way you will be able to debug it. Because since your "**TreeFra**" class does not exist the log should not appear. Try your luck!!